# set session wait_timeout inside of phpmyadmin for export/import

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, percona

I need to increase `wait_timeout` variable in mysql only when access mysql from **phpmyadmin**. I don't want to edit my.cnf file or set it globaly in mysql server.

I've read documentation, but haven't found if I can run any queries after connection to specific database.

Any help is appreciated.

Application details below:

> phpMyAdmin version 4.4.1
>
> mysql is percona 5.6.

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: Check `interactive_wait_timeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File:

libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php

```
138     public function connect(
```

before return link you can run query:

```
223         $link->query("SET SESSION wait_timeout = 600");
224         return $link;
```

This would set any session to mysql db from phpmyadmin with wait_timeout = 600.